# Test ExceptionNotification middleware in rails unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rack, middleware

I have a service class that I am testing. The service class makes an API call to an external resource. If the resource comes back empty, I would like to raise an exception that sends an email using the `ExceptionNotification` gem.

This gem operates as middleware and is usually not enabled in the test environment. However, in my service class test, I would like to test that the exception notification goes out as it's very important we are notified that the API request failed.

My understanding of middleware is that they are usually in the context of a request and an app. However, if I enable the `ExceptionNotification` gem in `config/environments/test.rb` and run my unit test, the exception notification email is sent out.

So, my question is how can I temporarily turn on and off this middleware for just this test without having an "app" to add it into, so I figure this must be possible without being in a feature spec.

Ok, here's the code I'm working with and started:

```
class MyService
  ThingNotFound = Class.new(Exception)

  def self.doit(params)
    the_thing = ApiResource.get_the_thing(params)
    raise ThingNotFound unless the_thing.present?
    return the_thing
  rescue ThingNotFound => e
    ExceptionNotifier.notify_exception(e, data: {params: params}) 
  end
end
```

In `config/environments/test.rb`, here is the `ExceptionNotifier` middleware code:

```
config.before_initialize do 
  MyApp::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hacky way I came up with. Open to alternatives. Essentially, when you include it in the test.rb, it instantiates the middleware which sets up some class variables so you can use it outside the context of a Rack app, so we just need to reproduce that.

```
 describe 'MyService' do

   before { ExceptionNotification::Rack.new(Recognize::Application, email: {:email_prefix => "[PREFIX] ", :sender_address => "whatever@whatever.com", :exception_recipients => %w(noone@noone.com)}) }
   after { ExceptionNotifier.class_variable_set("@@notifiers", {}) }

    it 'sends an exception email when no thing is found' do
      ApiResource.stub(get_the_thing: nil)
      expect{ MyService.doit({}) }.to change{ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.length}.by(1)
    end
 end
```

Comment: NOTE: I don't use the higher level interface of middleware.use because the array is frozen. So this is how you get around that. Yay, ruby!

Comment: What is `Recognize::Application`?

Comment: Thats just the name of my application